# Trying to gain a better grasp of loop logic.

Tags: java, while-loop, charat

I hope your Sunday is going well. So my goal in this little program is to print a new string with indexes [0,1] [4,5]...[12,13]... The loop functions only with an even numbered word that's greater than 4 letters. Why is this? Any advice on how to polish this turd would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LoopPractice {
public static void main(String[] args) {

  Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.print("Enter a String please: ");
  String str = myScanner.next();

  int count = 0;
  int x = 0;
  int y = 1;
  String emptyStr = "";

     while ( count != str.length() ) {

        emptyStr += str.charAt(x) + "" +  str.charAt(y);
        x += 4;
        y += 4;
        count += emptyStr.length();
     }
  System.out.print(emptyStr);

}
}
```

Comment: It is actually Monday where I am, and it is this type of thinking that will cause you many problems with programming

Comment: What op you are getting?

Comment: the word "kitten" --> kien

Comment: and the word "CodingConnor" --> Congnn

Comment: I strongly recommend NOT calling a variable `emptyStr`, unless it will always be empty.  Someone looking at `System.out.print(emptyStr);` at the bottom is going to wonder why you're printing empty string, but in fact, you're not.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure of your question, but the problem seems to be lying here: `x += 4; y += 4;`. You are incrementing those two variables by 4 each time (0, 4, 8 for X and 1, 5, 9 for Y).

When you are using the `.charAt` function, you are most likely getting an error which denotes some out of bounds issue since the values for X and Y are larger than the length of the string.

You will need to change the way that X and Y are incremented for you to stop getting that error.

Comment: @Carlitolos Also, as others have pointed out, you might want to take a look at yourr `while` condition.

Answer (score 0):

While condition, should check if you are not overflow string index:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LoopPractice {
public static void main(String[] args) {

  Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.print("Enter a String please: ");
  String str = myScanner.next();

  int x = 0;
  int y = 1;
  String emptyStr = "";

     while ( y <= str.length() ) {

        emptyStr += str.charAt(x) + "" +  str.charAt(y);
        x += 4;
        y += 4;
     }
  System.out.print(emptyStr);

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is all what you need :

```
System.out.print("Enter a String please: ");
String str = myScanner.next();
while(!str.isEmpty()){
          System.out.println(str.charAt(0)+""+str.charAt(1));
          if(str.length()>4)
              str = str.substring(4);
          else
              str = "";
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line

```
count += emptyStr.length();
```

Your `emptyStr` gets longer by two characters every time.  So the first time through, you add 2 to `count`.  The next time, you add 4, then 6, and so on.  So `count` takes the values 0, 2, 6, 12, 20 and so on.

If `str.length()` isn't one of those values, your loop will never end.